# VS2019 c++ solution Pre-Build Event using xcopy creating extra dll files during xcopy

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2019, xcopy, pre-build-event

I am using a Pre-Build Event in Visual Studio 2019 in my c++ solution to run xcopy in order to copy dll's and assets to the target build path.

This is the xcopy cmd I'm using: `xcopy /Y /D /E "$(SolutionDir)assets\*" "$(TargetDir)" <NUL:`

When using the debug build, it copies the dll's at the root of the assets directory I am copying from, but it also creates several duplicates of some of them with a 'd' at the end of the filename (ex: original assets path contains SDL2.dll and the target directory contains SDL2.dll and SDL2d.dll). It doesn't do this for all the dll's, or for any of them in the release build. But as you can see in the following photos, SDL2.dll in the release build has a different size than the original assets directory copy. I verified the assets directory copy was the same from the download I obtained from the [libsdl](https://www.libsdl.org/) site.

[This is an image of the assets directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muu6Y.png)

[This is an image of the debug build directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyLLG.png)

[This is an image of the release build directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1UgT.png)

The duplicate dll's have different sizes than the originals, and I imagine it has something to do with the debug build process. The application builds and runs in both configurations.

I have done everything I can find to separate the intermediate files from the output files in the configuration properties menu. I have incremental linking turned on for the debug release, hence the .ilk and .pdb files in the debug build directory. This issue is the last appearance of files in the target directory that I don't understand how they got there or why they are there. I was just wondering if this is normal behavior, and why there were additional versions of them appearing in the output directory.

Thanks all.

Comment: /E : Copies all subdirectories, even if they are empty. I sugges tou could try to use  `xcopy /y /d "..\..\XXX\$(IntDir)XXX.dll" "$(OutDir)"`   I suggest you could refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2019#to-copy-the-dll-in-a-post-build-event)

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT thanks for the suggestion, I want to populate the directories (even empty ones) during build

Comment: We should copy the DLL to the directory that contains your client executable.
<Source> :`"..\..\Filename\$(IntDir)Filename.dll"`
[<Destination>]: `"$(OutDir)"`